# How is this "connected dots" pattern done?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, illustrator-effects

I was wondering, if anyone could help me reproduce this "effect": [image: Illustrator]

I've noticed that this effect is often made with compound path, but I don't understand the process of it - do I have to make polygons at first and then make outline of them?

FYI: this background is downloaded from [freepik](http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-triangular-network-design_719713.htm#term=connected%20dots&page=1&position=3)

edit: Sorry, for wrong section and breaking few rules.. )=
I didn't want something specific, just random effect for company I've been working for- it's science related.

Im a big fan of poly-art (that's fairly easy to make for me), but I was really curious about this one, because it seemed to be more complicated than it should be.

However, question is answered in comments below.

thank you and may the force be with you.. (=

Comment: I'm going to venture out on a limb and go with the most obvious answer that I see - by hand.  Draw the lines, place some circles of various sizes on the intersections. lightly shade a few random polygons. Voila.  Maybe I'll make this a more in-depth answer in a second, I just got to work.

Comment: Compound path is often a symptom of being imported from another source.

Comment: Jonas Dralle: Thank you, that's exactly I've been looking for. Im fairly familiar with poly-art, so I have no problem reproduced this with hand, but I was looking for something less "time-consuming".

Comment: if you search for Plexus effect you'll find a plugin that generates it in After Effects and it can be exported as SVG http://aescripts.com/plexus/

Comment: @Luciano that plugin is $200 though! Probably too much to generate a background effect.

Comment: One might be able to make a triangle and then use a script to copy+translate+scale+rotate+set-opacity an arbitrary number of times within defined parameter limits.

Comment: @CAI OP didn't ask for prices...

Comment: @Luciano Fair enough, but I can't see a $200 After Effects plugin ever being a reasonable solution to creating a relatively simple vector image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is called "Plexus". [This](http://designtube.org/cont/plexus-photoshop-brushes) page seems to offer brushes to do this effect. Maybe you can find a good plugin for that. There's a good Plexus-Plugin for Adobe After Effects

*[This was originally a comment]*